# Unable to access certain endpoints even though I have Twitter Elevated API

Tags: r, api, twitter, rtweet

I have managed to receive my approval for Twitter Elevated API. However, when I try to run the code on R, I still receive this error message. Anybody knows what I am potentially doing wrong or if it will take a while for the system to update this access?

```
> country1 <- search_tweets(
+   '#Singapore', n = 100, include_rts = FALSE
+ )
Warning: You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve - 453
Warning message:
You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve
```

Comment: Have you got any clue? I'm also encountering this problem.